# basic summation using R

Tags: r, sum, standard-deviation

so I know there is a standard deviation function in R but im trying to figure out how to write code to figure out SD the long way using a for loop.

```
men<-c(150,175,213,241,190,132,110,208,187)
alex<-NULL
for(i in 1:length(men)
    {
    alex[i]<-(men[i]-178.44)^2

    }
```

this is what I have so far and what I am trying to do is store the value of (men[i]-mean)^2 in the vector alex so I can go on to sum the vector alex and find the standard deviation. however, I receive an error message when I try to run this code. Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for an R answer, or a java answer?

Comment: you forgot a `)` at the third line and it is better to avoid for loop in general in R. Have a look at the `apply` family function or best: use Richard solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since some calculations in R can be applied over entire vectors, you could simply write the following and forget the `for` loop all together.

```
> alex <- (men - mean(men))^2
> alex
# [1]  809.08642   11.86420 1194.08642 3913.19753  133.53086
# [6] 2157.08642 4684.64198  873.53086   73.19753
```

As per your comment, here is the way I'd do this with a `for` loop.  Notice the initialization of `alex` is a numeric vector with length exactly the same length as the vector we're calculating over.  This makes `for` loops run faster in R.

```
> alex <- numeric(length(men))
> for(i in 1:length(men))  alex[i] <- (men[i] - mean(men))^2
> alex
# [1]  809.08642   11.86420 1194.08642 3913.19753  133.53086
# [6] 2157.08642 4684.64198  873.53086   73.19753
```

Comment: thanks. so apparently x can represent men[i] or the whole vector its self? (in reference to "x-mean(x)"). any hints as to why/how they are differentiated or should I just accept the fact R works that way...

Comment: it does. would you mind editing in a solution using a for loop? currently taking an intro to stat course and thats pretty much all weve learned so far. if I were coding in java i would put a line at the end of the loop containing "return" or "alex[i]=___" but not sure how to do that in R

Comment: Ok, I added a `for` loop method.